# How do I compare values that I stored in a 2d array?

Tags: python

I am working on a project where the user inputs a layout for a crop field and the program says whether or not every crop is watered. (input c for crop and w for water source). A water source waters all 8 surrounding squares. An example of the program running would be:

[image: program]

This is the code I have so far:

```
rowCount = int(0)
columnCount = int(0)
array = []

#Ask user how many rows and columns
print ("Enter the number of rows and columns in the crop     field: ")
rows = int (input ("ROWS> "))
columns = int (input ("COLUMNS> "))

#insert user input into array
while (rowCount < rows) :
    rowCount += 1
    print ("ROW", rowCount, ">")
    x = input()
    array.insert(rowCount, [x])


#formats array properly
for r in array:
    for c in r:
        print (c)
        if "c" in array[0][0]:
                if "w" in array[0][1] or "w" in array[1][0] or "w" in array[1][1] :
                print ("that's not watered")
                
print ()
```

But I don't know where to go from here in order to compare the values in the array.

Comment: You need to split the rows at spaces.

Comment: `array.append(x.split())`

Comment: What is c and w?  How does the output (2, 3) and (3, 3) have to do with the table?  I am guessing you want the index of the 'c' but your array and output doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Read the data, then call watered() for each index to see it or the 8 surround squares are watered:

```
print("Enter the number of rows and columns in the crop field: ")
rows = int(input ("ROWS> "))
columns = int(input ("COLUMNS> "))
print("Input each row of the crop field.")
array = []
for i in range(rows):
    array.append(input("ROW%d> " % i).split(' '))

def watered(array, i, j):
    i_min = i - 1 if i > 0 else i
    i_max = i + 1 if i < len(array) - 1 else i
    j_min = j - 1 if j > 0 else j
    j_max = j + 1 if j < len(array[i]) - 1 else j
    for i in range(i_min, i_max + 1):
        for j in range(j_min, j_max + 1):
            if array[i][j] == 'w':
                return True
    return False

not_watered = []
for i, row in enumerate(array):
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        if not watered(array, i, j):
            not_watered.append((i, j))

if not_watered:
    print('Not all crops are watered!')
    print('OUTPUT False')
    print('The following crops are not watered:')
    print('OUTPUT', not_watered)
else:
    print('OUTPUT True')
```

You probably want to implement error checking (row > 0, columns > 0) and that the array you read in has the right number of columns and the right values in each column.  You can probably do better than testing the same field up to 9 times though.

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to what I was looking for. I edited my question because it was not clear before, but if there is a 'c' next to or diagonal from a 'w' then it is considered watered and the output at the end points out the c's that are not close enough to a w.

Comment: If you are all set, mark it accepted so others don't spend time trying to answer it.

Comment: I updated my answer with your definition of watered.